# Adding ? Sign to XML.DocumentElement

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-7, omnixml

I'm working with Delphi 7 and OmniXML and am trying to create a document and I need to have the DocumentElement be:

> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

But I can't understand how to add the last `?` sign.

My code:

```
var    
  xml: IXMLDocument;   
begin    
  xml := ConstructXMLDocument('?xml');    
  SetNodeAttr(xml.DocumentElement, 'version', '1.0');   
  SetNodeAttr(xml.DocumentElement, 'encoding', 'UTF-8');    
  XMLSaveToFile(xml, 'C:\Test1.xml', ofIndent);  
end;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

This is not the **Document Element**. It is not even an element, it is a **Processing Instruction** instead, and it happens to be the XML declaration, sometimes also known as the XML prolog.

To specify the attributes of the XML declaration, use this instead:

```
xmlDoc.CreateProcessingInstruction('xml', 'version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"');
```

For example:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  OmniXML;

var
  XMLDoc: IXMLDocument;
  ProcessingInstruction: IXMLProcessingInstruction;
  DocumentElement: IXMLElement;
begin
  XMLDoc := CreateXMLDoc;
  ProcessingInstruction := XMLDoc.CreateProcessingInstruction('xml',
    'version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"');
  DocumentElement := XMLDoc.CreateElement('foo');

  XMLDoc.DocumentElement := DocumentElement;
  XMLDoc.InsertBefore(ProcessingInstruction, DocumentElement);

  XMLDoc.Save('foo.xml', ofIndent);
end.
```

Comment: Oh, okay, got it now! Thanks.